# Referencing Objects in a Vector of Objects

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, vector

1. I need to create a vector or list of objects(whichever is going to allow me to do this).
2. Instantiate an object and add it to the vector or list of objects.
3. I need to reference an object in a vector of objects(or list of objects) and reference a component of that object to initialize a variable stored in a Game Manager.

Note: This is not a homework assignment or work related. This is a personal game mechanic I'm working on. I can accomplish one and two. Three is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure whether to use a vector or a list and I don't know how to reference a specific object in that vector or list in Unity C#(using MonoDevelop)(Singleton Pattern).

```
instance = Instantiate (prefab, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation); 
instance.GetComponent<Camera> ().enabled = false; 
cameraTwo = instance.GetComponent<Camera> ();
```

The cameraTwo variable needs to be set to the component of an object in a vector or list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure you have read the [ask] topics. In particular, in your case we need a [mcve]; otherwise, your question will be closed soon as off-topic or too broad one.

Comment: "This is where I´m stuck" Please show your **code**.

Comment: instance = Instantiate (prefab, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
   instance.GetComponent<Camera> ().enabled = false;
   cameraTwo = instance.GetComponent<Camera> ();

Comment: The cameraTwo variable needs to be set to the component of an object in a vector or list.

Comment: What is the type of items in your list? By "cameraTwo variable needs to be set to the component of an object", do you mean that items in your list have members of type 'Camera' or do you need to dynamically add new component to the GameObjects in your list (with GameObject.AddComponent)

Comment: @MikkoKoivisto The items in my list have camera components that I need to access. The problem is having to point to that specific object to grab its component.

Answer (score 0):

> The items in my list have camera components that I need to access. The problem is having to point to that specific object to grab its component.

You could use System.Linq to find items that have Camera component.

```
using System.Linq;
...
List<GameObject> myList = new List<GameObject>();
public GameObject GetGameObjectWithCameraComponent() {
    return myList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.GetComponent<Camera>() != null);
}

public IEnumerable<GameObject> GetAllGameObjectsWithCameraComponent() {
    return myList.Where(item => item.GetComponent<Camera>() != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List [0].GetComponent ();
Problem solved. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Don't forget to check for List.Length or List.Count to avoid NPEs.